# How to query for only a certain attribute

Tags: java, mongodb

Suppose I want to query for only a certain attribute of all documents, something like in SQL:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME
FROM TABLE1
```

How can I do it with Mongo and it's Java API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Java API, you can do it like this. You have to explicitly turn off the _id field, in order to exclude it.

```
Mongo m = new Mongo();
DB db = m.getDB( "test" );

DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("test");       
coll.insert(new BasicDBObject("Name","Wes").append("x", "to have a second field"));
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(); 
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("Name",1).append("_id",false);
DBCursor curs = coll.find(query, fields);

while(curs.hasNext()) {
  DBObject o = curs.next();
  System.out.println(o.toString());
}
```

Output:

```
{ "Name" : "Wes"}
```

Update for sort:

```
coll.insert(new BasicDBObject("Name","Wes").append("x", "to have a second field"));
coll.insert(new BasicDBObject("Name","Alex").append("x", "to have a second field"));
coll.insert(new BasicDBObject("Name","Zeus").append("x", "to have a second field"));
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(); 
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("Name",1).append("_id",false);
BasicDBObject orderBy = new BasicDBObject("Name",1);
DBCursor curs = coll.find(query, fields).sort(orderBy);
while(curs.hasNext()) {
   DBObject o = curs.next();
   System.out.println(o.toString());
}
```

Gives:

```
{ "Name" : "Alex"}
{ "Name" : "Wes"}
{ "Name" : "Zeus"}
```

Comment: I am also interested in sorting the results. I tried adding coll.find(query, fields).sort(fields); but it doesn't seem to do the trick

Comment: You wouldn't want to use fields, because it has that _id:false in it. Added an update to show you how sort works.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all documents, use an *empty* object as the first argument. With the second one you only get the field `FIRSTNAME`.

```
db.table1.find({}, {'FIRSTNAME': 1});
```

See the [documentation on querying](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying) for more details.